# "Take the tour" style balloon popups similar to facebook?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to show the user around on the page on the first visit, like "Take the tour".
I would show a balloon popup pointing at the first element to be described on the web page, for instance the search box. The popup would contain a text description of the element as well as Previous / Next buttons, and some title saying "1 of 7" or similar. Clicking next should show the next hint "2 of 7" at another element.

I have seen this in both Facebook and in Adobe Lightroom (not web!) when introducing new features, as a reference to what I'm looking for.

Is there a plugin suitable or easily adapted for this? I don't want to reinvent the wheel but I'm not sure what to search for on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:
http://jwarby.github.io/jquery-pagewalkthrough/

Once configured you can instantiate it by calling:

```
$('body').pagewalkthrough(options);
```

Comment: Thanks that works. However the plugin has issues with window resizing and the usage documentation is not entirely clear.

Comment: Glad that helped, but I was trying to point you in the right direction you can search for that on google and will give you related plugins, like this page: http://www.sitepoint.com/web-tour-instructional-plugins/ if you find this response helpful plese mark it as the right one

Answer (score 1):

You could use :
Bootstrap tour: http://bootstraptour.com/

Answer (score 0):

try this jquery balloon plugin

https://urin.github.io/jquery.balloon.js/

Comment: Thanks, but simple balloons was not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The **Joyride** plugin seems to be one of the most comprehensive and mature page walktrough plugins. Tips are written as li elements. Footprint 27kB + jQuery + modernizr.
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/joyride.html

If you are looking to configure using only js, then **Feature Walkthrough** is an option. Footprint 8kB + jQuery.
http://nbprithv.github.io/introtour-ui/

If you require better control over interactivity at each step, then **Tourist** is an option:
http://easelinc.github.io/tourist/

There are many more to look at (as Federico M. Rinaldi pointed out):
http://www.sitepoint.com/web-tour-instructional-plugins/
http://galenking.com/post/49426435422/a-roundup-of-jquery-walkthroughfeature-tour